# Decrypt Google KMS column in BigQuery

Tags: encryption, google-bigquery

I'm trying to encrypt some columns in my Google BigQuery table.The algorithm uses 256-bit Advanced Encryption Standard (AES-256) keys in Galois Counter Mode (GCM), padded with Cloud KMS-internal metadata.

Is it possible from my reporting service (e.g PBI / SSRS) do the decryption? I saw from this documentation we can decrypt using multiple languages, but not sure if it's possible to integrate with my reporting service

> https://cloud.google.com/kms/docs/encrypt-decrypt#kms-decrypt-symmetric-gcloud

Comment: Hi @HanChris, Can you please clarify more on your use case? Are you using Customer-managed encryption keys or Customer-supplied encryption keys?

Comment: Hi @PrajnaRaiT, I'm using CMEK

Comment: Currently it’s not possible to decrypt the cloud KMS columns in BigQuery using SQL Server Reporting Services (SSRS). If you want this feature to be enabled, you can open a new feature request on the [issue tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) describing your requirement.